# Using Wordpress, how can I display posts that are in multiple categories?

Tags: loops, categories, wordpress

I am trying to retrieve posts in Wordpress that belong in two categories. **Each post must belong in both categories**.

Here is my query:

```
<?php $myPosts = new WP_Query('category_name=featured+news&posts_per_page=10'); ?>

<?php if($myPosts->have_posts()) : ?>

     <?php while($myPosts->have_posts()) : $myPosts->the_post(); ?>

         <article>
             <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
             <?php the_content(); ?>
         </article>

     <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

In this example, 'featured' and 'news' are the slugs of two categories. I am using the plus symbol (+) with the 'category_name' parameter in my query to indicate that posts must be in *both* categories, as suggested [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters).

For some reason, this isn't working and I'm not sure why. I am getting this error:

`PHP Warning:  urldecode() expects parameter 1 to be string`

It's referencing the query.php file:

`wp-includes/query.php`

Why can the query not interpret `featured+news` as a string? I figure I must be missing something. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: what is the output of var_dump?

Comment: When I `var_dump($myPosts)` I get an array that contains `["category_name"]=> string(12) "featured news"` and `["posts"]=> array(0)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the plus symbol (+) isn't working but using `category__and` instead works.

```
$featuredID = get_category_by_slug('featured')->term_id;

$newsID = get_category_by_slug('news')->term_id;

$myPosts = new WP_Query(array('category__and' => array($featuredID, $newsID), 'posts_per_page' => 10));
```